# Child component rendering before props are ready

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm fairly sure I know the problem. I think its because of the child component rendering before its props are ready. After looking at many tutorials and docs I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I am using hooks and useEffect to get Data from firestore when the page opens. after that, I want to pass the data to a child component "Table.js" to be displayed.
If I have the table in the parent component it works fine, but as soon as I move the table to its own component i get an error saying forms.map is not a function `TypeError: forms.map is not a function

Here is my code for the parent component **MainScreen.js**

`

```
  function MainScreen() {
  const [forms, setForms] = useState([]);
  let history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const unsubscribe = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("")
        .doc("")
        .collection("")
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          const newForms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
          }));

          setForms(newForms);
        });
      return () => unsubscribe();
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);



  const openSignFormPage = () => {
    history.push("/");
  };

  console.log("MainScreen forms:", forms);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        margin: "auto",
        padding: "2% 4%"
      }}>
      {!forms.length ? <div>Loading</div> : <MyTable forms={forms} />}

      <div
        style={{
          border: "solid red 1px",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-around"
        }}>
        <Button color={"blue"} onClick={openSignFormPage}>
          Sign forms
        </Button>
        <Button color={"blue"}>Create / Edit forms</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default MainScreen;
```

Code for **Table.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    overflowX: "auto"
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 650
  }
});

const MyTable = forms => {
  let history = useHistory();

  const classes = useStyles();
  //const forms = useForms("yVhc97ImwzFRz6Kh7Mbn");
  console.log("Table Page forms: ", forms);

  const openViewDisclaimerPage = row => {
    history.push("/viewform", { ...row });
  };

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Child Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Time in</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Time out</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Parent Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>shoe Box Number</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {forms.map(row => (
            <TableRow
              hover
              onClick={() => openViewDisclaimerPage(row)}
              key={row.id}>
              <TableCell component={"th"} scope={"row"}>
                {row.children &&
                  row.children.length &&
                  row.children[0].childName}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.timeIn}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.timeOut}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.parentName}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.shoeBoxNumber}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default MyTable;
```

When changing the code a bit to try a different approach, it renders loading, the data then is ready, but doesn't re-render and just stays on the loading screen.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: `const MyTable = ({forms}) =>` You get the props here and need to destructure.

Comment: As mentioned above destruct the forms from props, then conditional render `forms? forms.map(...):<div>No form data!</div>`

Comment: @colburton Yup that worked! Thank you :) I guess that's my lack of understanding for react. I was just about to point out as well as an update, that it was showing the loading screen, then rendering the child component as it should, but then it was saying forms.map is not a function, so at this point, I knew it was no longer a data loading issue. Thank you, what could I have used to find out that this was the problem?

Comment: @colburton do you want to add your comment, as an answer so I can accept it. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong syntax to consume props:

```js
const MyTable = forms => {
  ...
}
```

It should be:

```js
const MyTable = ({ forms }) => {
```

You also not returning unsubscribe from your `useEffect()` callback. It should be:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  ...
  return fetchData();
}, []);
```

or you can even remove `fetchData()` and use it's body instead:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   const unsubscribe = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("")
        .doc("")
        .collection("")
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          const newForms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
          }));

          setForms(newForms);
        });
      return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, as @colburton said in comment above I need to const MyTable = ({forms}) => to destructure, that worked for me. I just had question about the 2nd part of your answer. dont you need to have async in the function before you can call await? I tried you useEffect code but got an error saying await, must be in a async function, which I know it has to.

Comment: You're right, i missed you have await there. My answer was about highlighting that you might have a problems with unsubscribing since you're not returning this function for `useEffect()` callback